# Run 'Long Wait' Script On Page Load, With AJAX Check If Its Finished

Tags: php, ajax, timer, loading

I have a webpage that i am embedding a script in that could take up to 10 minutes to run backend.

I have tried many different versions of an ajax script loader with a timer.

What i need:
On Page Load, I need to trigger the main working script to run.
The very last line of this script will create a unique text file in a folder, with filename of the user, so that the file appears once the script has completed.

And, then triggered from page load also, would be an AJAX function, to load a second script every 10 seconds,
this seconds script is very minimal, and checks if the user file (from script above) is in the specified dir.

If the file is not there yet (script still working), then it echoes

```
<img src"../loading.gif">
```

and if the file is now there (script has finished), then it echoes a link (or maybe a header to another page, i haven't decided about that yet)...

this will mean that on page load, the main processing script starts, and also trigger the ajax script (which will instantly display loading image), and once the main script has finished executing, the loading image will change to a link (or maybe just re-direct you to another page)

sorry for rambling, just tying to give as much info as possible...

ps, i presume i will need a simple load once ajax function to call the main processing script, so that it works in the background, or the main page will take ages to load

my latest attempt:

```
function MakeRequest()
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET", "processing_script.php?user=<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>", true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function HandleResponse(response)
{
  document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = response;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your exact question just isn't clear to me... Could you clarify?

Comment: ok, i have a script that copies alot of files on my server... i need it to run that on page load, and tell the user when its finished... the log file on my server can be created for each user at end of processing the file copy, which would enable a small script to check if file there or not, and whether to display loading image or link

Comment: im presuming it would be two seperate ajax functions, one for the main script (no need to put any info from that in a div), and one for the log file check script that would need to echo the script contents into a div

Comment: lol, my question is, how do i configure an ajax request correctly to ... 1 . load a file ... 2 . load another file every 5 seconds and print the results into a div

Comment: [review] Please update your question with the actual question. Nobody wants to read a bunch of comments to understand your problem. Also, it would be nice, if you correct the lowercase in the latter part of your question and in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

To load a file every 5 seconds you could call your function every xy seconds with the [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function.

Have you considered using a javascript framework such as jquery? They provide some very easy to use ajax-methods to simplify the whole process. Handling an ajax-request "manually" is always a "pain in the ass" to me.